# Using parmest with pyomo.dae for parameter estimation

Tags: python, pyomo

I have a model and I want to estimate the values of the variables using `parmest` in pyomo.

Using parmest, I got a **KeyError**, and I can't figure out why.

Below is my code:

```
# Import the needed libraries
from pyomo.environ import *                            # in order to be able to use all the functions in pyomo
from pyomo.dae import *                                # for solving dynamic models in pyomo
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import pytest
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pyomo.contrib.parmest.parmest as parmest

# Load the important  data
data = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

def M1_Model(data):
    '''
    function to create Pyomo model
    Argument:
        data: a single dictionary of data
    Return:
        m: Pyomo model
    '''
    # load other necessary data
    df2 = pd.read_csv('Steady_State_Output.csv')
    df3 = pd.read_csv('M1_Parameters.csv')
    
    # unpack the data into the respective temporary variables
    Ssu_temp = data['S_su']
    Sac_temp = data['S_ac']
    SIN_temp = data['S_IN']
    Q_temp = data['Q']
    time_temp = data['time']
    
    # Create dictionaries for data of the state variables indexed by the timestep
    Ssu_meas={}
    Sac_meas={}
    SIN_meas={}
    Q_meas={}
    for i,j in enumerate(time_temp):
        Ssu_meas[float(j)] = Ssu_temp[i]
        Sac_meas[float(j)] = Sac_temp[i]
        SIN_meas[float(j)] = SIN_temp[i]
        Q_meas[float(j)] = Q_temp[i]
    
    # Define pyomo model
    m = ConcreteModel()
    
    # define the data timesteps as Pyomo ContinuousSet
    # m.t = ContinuousSet(bounds=(0.0, time_temp.iloc[-1]), initialize=time_temp.tolist())
    m.t = ContinuousSet(bounds=(0,19), initialize=time_temp.tolist())
    
    # define 'experimental' data as Pyomo parameters indexed by timestep set and 
    # initialized by dictionary of experimental data
    m.Ssu_in = Param(m.t, initialize=Ssu_meas, mutable=True)
    m.Sac_in = Param(m.t, initialize=Sac_meas, mutable=True)
    m.S_IN_in = Param(m.t, initialize=SIN_meas, mutable=True)
    m.Q = Param(m.t, initialize=Q_meas, mutable=True)
    
    # Define the parameters and variables you are trying to estimate    
    m.k_dis = Var(initialize=0.5, bounds=(0,5))     # d^-1
    m.S_su = Var(m.t, initialize=(df2.iat[0,0]), bounds=(0,50))             # kgCOD m^-3
    
    # Outlet Concentration Variables
    m.S_ac = Var(m.t, initialize=(df2.iat[0,6]), domain=PositiveReals, bounds=(0,3000))      # kgCOD m^-3 
    m.S_IN = Var(m.t, initialize=(df2.iat[0,10]), domain=PositiveReals, bounds=(0,3000))      # kmole N m^-3
    
    # DerivativeVar
    m.dS_su_dt = DerivativeVar(m.S_su, wrt=m.t)
    m.dS_ac_dt = DerivativeVar(m.S_ac, wrt=m.t)
    m.dS_IN_dt = DerivativeVar(m.S_IN, wrt=m.t)
    
    # Constraints
    def S_su_out_bal(m,t):
        return m.dS_su_dt[t] == (m.Q[t]/3400) * (m.Ssu_in[t] - m.S_su[t]) + (0.000662979*m.k_dis)
    m.Ssu_outcon = Constraint(m.t, rule=S_su_out_bal)
    
    def S_ac_out_bal(m,t):
        return m.dS_ac_dt[t] == (m.Q[t]/3400) * (m.Sac_in[t] - m.S_ac[t]) + (0.00202160*m.k_dis)
    m.Sac_outcon = Constraint(m.t, rule=S_ac_out_bal)
    
    def S_IN_out_bal(m,t):
        return m.dS_IN_dt[t] == (m.Q[t]/3400) * (m.S_IN_in[t] - m.S_IN[t]) + (0.005667982*m.k_dis)
    m.SIN_outcon = Constraint(m.t, rule=S_IN_out_bal)
    
    
    # initial conditions
    m.S_su[0].unfix()  # df2.iat[0,0]
    m.S_ac[0].fix(df2.iat[0,6])
    m.S_IN[0].fix(df2.iat[0,10])
    
    # Discretize model using Finite Difference Method
    discretizer = TransformationFactory('dae.finite_difference')
    discretizer.apply_to(m,nfe=19,wrt=m.t,scheme='BACKWARD')
    
    # Define the objective function
    # Objective Function
    def ComputeFirstStageCost_rule(m):
        return 0
    m.FirstStageCost = Expression(rule=ComputeFirstStageCost_rule)
    
    def ComputeSecondStageCost_rule(m):
        return sum( (m.S_su[t] - m.Ssu_in[t])**2 + (m.S_ac[t] - m.Sac_in[t])**2 + (m.S_IN[t] - m.S_IN_in[t])**2 \
               for t in m.t)
    m.SecondStageCost = Expression(rule=ComputeSecondStageCost_rule)
    
    # return the sum of the first-stage and second-stage costs as the objective function
    def total_cost_rule(m):
        return m.FirstStageCost + m.SecondStageCost
    m.Total_Cost_Objective = Objective(rule=total_cost_rule, sense=minimize)
    
    # return initialised model
    return m

# Parameters and Variables to estimate 
theta_names = ['k_dis', 'S_su']

# Create an instance of the parmest estimator
pest = parmest.Estimator(M1_Model, data, theta_names, tee=True)

# Parameter estimation
obj, theta = pest.theta_est()
```

I got the error below:

```
KeyError: 0

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_16592\1865652207.py in <cell line: 8>()
      6 
      7 # Parameter estimation
----> 8 obj, theta = pest.theta_est()

c:\users\olade\anaconda3\envs\watertap\lib\site-packages\pyomo\contrib\parmest\parmest.py in theta_est(self, solver, return_values, calc_cov, cov_n)
    918             ), "The number of datapoints must be greater than the number of parameters to estimate"
    919 
--> 920         return self._Q_opt(
    921             solver=solver,
    922             return_values=return_values,

c:\users\olade\anaconda3\envs\watertap\lib\site-packages\pyomo\contrib\parmest\parmest.py in _Q_opt(self, ThetaVals, solver, return_values, bootlist, calc_cov, cov_n)
    516             )
    517         else:
--> 518             ef = local_ef.create_EF(
    519                 scen_names,
    520                 _experiment_instance_creation_callback,

c:\users\olade\anaconda3\envs\watertap\lib\site-packages\pyomo\contrib\parmest\utils\create_ef.py in create_EF(scenario_names, scenario_creator, scenario_creator_kwargs, EF_name, suppress_warnings, nonant_for_fixed_vars)
     98     if scenario_creator_kwargs is None:
     99         scenario_creator_kwargs = dict()
--> 100     scen_dict = {
    101         name: scenario_creator(name, **scenario_creator_kwargs)
    102         for name in scenario_names

c:\users\olade\anaconda3\envs\watertap\lib\site-packages\pyomo\contrib\parmest\utils\create_ef.py in <dictcomp>(.0)
     99         scenario_creator_kwargs = dict()
    100     scen_dict = {
--> 101         name: scenario_creator(name, **scenario_creator_kwargs)
    102         for name in scenario_names
    103     }

c:\users\olade\anaconda3\envs\watertap\lib\site-packages\pyomo\contrib\parmest\parmest.py in _experiment_instance_creation_callback(scenario_name, node_names, cb_data)
    158     # at least three signatures are supported. The first is preferred
    159     try:
--> 160         instance = callback(experiment_number=exp_num, cb_data=cb_data)
    161     except TypeError:
    162         raise RuntimeError(

c:\users\olade\anaconda3\envs\watertap\lib\site-packages\pyomo\contrib\parmest\parmest.py in _instance_creation_callback(self, experiment_number, cb_data)
    467         else:
    468             raise RuntimeError(f'Unexpected data format for cb_data={cb_data}')
--> 469         model = self._create_parmest_model(exp_data)
    470 
    471         return model

c:\users\olade\anaconda3\envs\watertap\lib\site-packages\pyomo\contrib\parmest\parmest.py in _create_parmest_model(self, data)
    394         Modify the Pyomo model for parameter estimation
    395         """
--> 396         model = self.model_function(data)
    397 
    398         if (len(self.theta_names) == 1) and (

~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_16592\2356220605.py in M1_Model(data)
     27     Q_meas={}
     28     for i,j in enumerate(time_temp):
---> 29         Ssu_meas[float(j)] = Ssu_temp[i]
     30         Sac_meas[float(j)] = Sac_temp[i]
     31         SIN_meas[float(j)] = SIN_temp[i]

c:\users\olade\anaconda3\envs\watertap\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1005 
   1006         elif key_is_scalar:
-> 1007             return self._get_value(key)
   1008 
   1009         if is_hashable(key):

c:\users\olade\anaconda3\envs\watertap\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in _get_value(self, label, takeable)
   1114 
   1115         # Similar to Index.get_value, but we do not fall back to positional
-> 1116         loc = self.index.get_loc(label)
   1117 
   1118         if is_integer(loc):

c:\users\olade\anaconda3\envs\watertap\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key)
   3653             return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3654         except KeyError as err:
-> 3655             raise KeyError(key) from err
   3656         except TypeError:
   3657             # If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error will raise

KeyError: 0
```